# Java Mail Delegation Access not working for Office 365

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, office365

If you see the commented line of code store.connect.... I am trying to access the shared mailbox through a usermail box [migrated to cloud] which has a delegate access on this shared mailbox. On running this I get

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
  at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:715)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
  at com.adecco.smpt.TestSSL.main(TestSSL.java:26)
```

If I try to access user-mail box instead of shared mailbox **everything works well**. Is there a different syntax to access the SHARED MAILBOX in JAVA ?? Thanks in advance.

```java
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;

public class TestSSL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(true);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "office 365 username/alias name of shared MAILBOX", "PASSWORD");

            System.out.println(store);
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
            for (Message message : messages) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one more think - I already configured the shared mailbox in OUTLOOK using the delegate access and it configured successfully.

Comment: Hey @AVI, are you using the password for the shared outlook mailbox only? Can you help me the completed configuration?